# Interface "overloading" in a shared library written in fortran

Tags: fortran, shared-libraries

I am quite new to fortran. Currently I am having trouble creating an "overloaded" subroutine that is accessed by customers via a shared library. What I wanted to do was add an argument to an existing function, but without breaking current implementations. Therefore I want to acces both the old and the new functionality via the old subroutines name. I tried to achieve this by interfacing the old subroutine name so it could take either the old number or the new number of arguments.

Old code is similar to this:

```
module LibraryMod
    use SomeClass
    implicit none

    public :: ExposedSubroutine

contains
    subroutine ExposedSubroutine(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        type(SomeClassType), intent(inout) :: arg1
        integer, intent(inout) :: arg2
        integer, intent(inout) :: arg3
            ...
    end subroutine ExposedSubroutine
end module LibraryMod
```

My new implementation is similar to this:

```
module LibraryMod
    use SomeClass
    implicit none

    public :: ExposedSubroutine
    public :: ExposedSubroutine_With_3_args
    public :: ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args

    interface ExposedSubroutine
        module procedure ExposedSubroutine_With_3_args
        module procedure ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args
    end interface ExposedSubroutine

contains
    subroutine ExposedSubroutine_With_3_args(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        type(SomeClassType), intent(inout) :: arg1
        integer, intent(inout) :: arg2
        integer, intent(inout) :: arg3
        logical :: arg4
        arg4 = .FALSE.
        call ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    end subroutine ExposedSubroutine_With_3_args

    subroutine ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        type(SomeClassType), intent(in) :: arg1
        type(SomeClassType), intent(inout) :: arg2
        integer, intent(inout) :: arg3
        logical, intent(in) :: arg4
            ...
    end subroutine ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args
end module LibraryMod
```

With other words, ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args is the old ExposedSubroutine including an if statement where the new functionality is triggered. However with the new implementation I can not find the interface ExposedSubroutine in the shared library. Also, it does not appear when I try to examine the shared library with for example "nm -D library.so".

Is it possible to solve this with an interface? Anyone have experiences with how this can be handled in another way?

The most optimal solution would include only one subroutine call for the users of the library that could take either 3 or 4 arguments.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the Welcome [tour]. I do not understand the problem, What does "However with the new implementation I can not find the interface ExposedSubroutine in the shared library." exactly mean? What did you do?

Comment: Why do you expect `ExposedSubroutine` to be in the shared library? Wouldn't resolution of such a generic interface be a compile-time problem rather than something for the linker or loader to worry about? It's not obvious to me why your "optimal solution" is appropriate for your use case, so can you provide more detail?

Comment: @VladimirF I mean that after compilation, there is no generic subroutine named "ExposedSubroutine" - so any attempt to compile programs that use the shared library fail due to "undefined reference". The other subroutines, "ExposedSubroutine_With_4_args" and "ExposedSubroutine_With_3_args" can be accessed, but I want them to be accessed via the interface.

Comment: @joaryd There is no such subroutine compiled. The interface is the instruction for the compiler to call one of the specific subroutines. Nothing more.

Comment: @francescalus Well, I suppose I expected it to be in my shared library due to the "public :: ExposedSubroutine" which I though would kind of forward declare the generic subroutine. The compilation of the library succeeds, but I can only access the other subroutines from it.

Some of our customers need the new functionality and others don't. We could ship two different subroutines where one uses the new functionality and require them to implement that, but it would require some refactoring of code on their part and possibly in some other parts that we ship aswell.

Comment: Fortran doesn't have variadic procedures, so it's not clear why it's "optimal" to solve this at link time. If your customers are using Fortran compilers, provide the interface definition to them and let their Fortran compiler resolve the generic to the appropriate specific procedure when compiling. If your customers aren't using Fortran compilers then we'll need more detail to be able to advise further.

Comment: Fortran has optional parameters so you don't need variadic procedures.  Just check for the presence of a variable.  There are quite a few examples of how to do this - lookup **Fortran optional parameters**